# Repeating a background texture forever in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

My "game" works with a pretty large playing field, so I need a repeating background. I've implemented this the following way:

Loading:

```
assetManager.get("texture_bg.png", Texture.class).setWrap(Repeat, Repeat);
bgRegion = new TextureRegion(assetManager.get("texture_bg.png", Texture.class));
bgRegion.setRegion(0, 0, 16384, 16384);
```

Drawing:

```
batch.draw(bgRegion, 0, 0);
```

This does as expected: Creates a background of 16384 by 16384 pixels from a 512x512px texture. But now that I'm getting further in the testing, I foresee running out of space quickly almost no matter what I set the region to.

Is there a way I can have it simply repeat forever and not specifying a finite number?

Comment: Could you not just simply add a couple of background images after one another and move the images that are off-screen in front of the character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to make a Really Large Sprite because it will just look bad when you hit the limits of floating point precision (when it gets larger than 2^24).

it just needs to be at least large enough to cover your screen + an extra 512 pixels, and then just render `batch.draw(bgRegion, camera.x % 512, camera.y % 512)`. Since the texture repeats every 512 pixels, you won't notice that it's moving.